# Hibernate over multiple VMs

Tags: java, hibernate, virtual-machine

Is it possible to use Hibernate over multiple virtual machines ?

Example: `foo.getBar()` to lazy retrieve the `Bar` into a virtual machine (VM2) `foo` is passed to from the virtual machine (VM1) Hibernate is running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use terracota.

Check this [link](http://www.terracotta.org/start/start-hibernate).